# iOS UITableView limit reordering only in one section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've a `UITableView` with 2 sections. The rows in section 0 can be reordered, while rows in section 1 can't.

How I can avoid move rows from section 0 to section 1 ?

Comment: Can you show your tableView Datasource methods.

Comment: did u find the solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the table view delegate method  `tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:` to check the proposed index path and return an index path in a different section if the user choice isn't acceptable.